# Android Google Map not drawing the last polyline

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

I would like to implement the polygon adding module that showing yellow lines for current device is going, red lines for history track. But when it comes to the execution. I have found that the last line between the yellow pin and red pin is not drawn. I have tried setting the subList parameters to set the subList of points to be drawn but it is in vail to draw the last segment. Would you please tell me how to draw the last segment of the polyline ?

[image]
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  implements LocationListener {

```
    final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;

    private GoogleMap myMap;
    Location myLocation;
    LocationManager lm;
    private ArrayList<Checkpoint> cpList = new ArrayList<Checkpoint> ();
    private ArrayList<Marker> thisMarkerList = new ArrayList<Marker> ();
    private List<LatLng> ppoints = new ArrayList<LatLng> ();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportMapFragment sFragment =  (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        myMap =  sFragment.getMap();
        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService (LOCATION_SERVICE);
        String provider = lm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
        Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if(loc!=null)
        {
            onLocationChanged(loc);
        }

        myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(setting());

    }


    private OnMapLongClickListener setting() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new OnMapLongClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d (point.toString() , "user one long click");

                Checkpoint cp = new Checkpoint("Destination", point, 0);
                cpList.add(cp);
                Checkpoint lastlyAdded = cpList.get(cpList.size() -1 );
                Log.d("size" , String.valueOf(cpList.size()));

                //  myMap.clear();
                for(int i = 0 ; i < cpList.size() ; i ++){
                    Checkpoint cPoint =  cpList.get(i);
                    if(!cPoint.getPoint().equals(lastlyAdded.getPoint())){
                        cPoint.setState(1); 
                        cPoint.setDesp("Checkpoint "+String.valueOf(i+1) );
                    }
                }
                addMarkersToMap();
            }};
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

        if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    RQS_GooglePlayServices);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude() , location.getLongitude());
        myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
    }


    private void addMarkersToMap() {
        myMap.clear();
        ppoints.clear();
        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = null ;
        LatLng ll; 
        for (int i = 0; i < cpList.size(); i++) {         
            ll = new LatLng(cpList.get(i).getPoint().latitude, cpList.get(i).getPoint().longitude);
            BitmapDescriptor bitmapMarker;
            polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            polylineOptions.color(Color.YELLOW);
            polylineOptions.width(5);
            switch (cpList.get(i).getState()) {
            case 0:
                bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW);               
                break;
            case 1:
                bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED);  
                break;
            case 2:
                bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE);
                break;
            default:
                bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED);
                break;
            }   
            ppoints.add(ll);
            thisMarkerList.add(myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ll).title(cpList.get(i).getDesp()) 
                    .snippet(String.valueOf(cpList.get(i).getPoint().latitude) + "," + 
                            String.valueOf(cpList.get(i).getPoint().longitude))
                            .icon(bitmapMarker)));

        }
        int length  = ppoints.size();
        if(length >2){
myMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.RED).addAll(ppoints.subList(0, ppoints.size())));
        myMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.YELLOW).addAll(ppoints.subList(ppoints.size()-2, ppoints.size())));
        }else{

            myMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.YELLOW).addAll(ppoints));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: instead of addAll to yellow color polyline just say add

Comment: you sure the last index has latlong try to print it

Comment: I finally use addALL using sublist between second last and point size() length .. it seems to take two points ..( last node and second last node )